# Invoking AWS SNS causes .net app to exit without hitting exception breakpoint

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have the following code:

```
private async Task SendSmsAlert(string responseValue)
    {
        try
        {
            IAmazonSimpleNotificationService snsClient = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
            
            var request = new PublishRequest
            {
                TopicArn = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:2XXXXXXX25:my-topic-name",
                Message = $"Alert: The value {responseValue} is below the threshold",
            };
            var response = await snsClient.PublishAsync(request);
            Console.WriteLine($"Successfully published message ID: {response.MessageId}");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var ex = e.InnerException;
        }
    }
```

With the ARN of the topic copied from the console. I've done a test message from the console and both SMS and Email are received fine. However, when I execute the above code, the line that calls PublishAsync causes the program to exit. There are no exceptions thrown (looking in the output window), the breakpoint in the catch block is never hit and if I step through, it just exits.

Can anyone help with why this may be or how to diagnose whats blowing up here?

Thanks

Comment: Windows Event log - Application (assuming you're using Windows) should show something if it's an unmanaged exception.

Comment: It seems the caller of this method `SendSmsAlert` is not using `await`.

Comment: Yes, its being invoked: await SendSmsAlert(currentBalance.ToString());

Comment: Nothing in the windows event log I'm afraid

Comment: Is it being invoked async all the way up the stack?

Comment: Was this resolved? Keen to understand what the issue was here. IDE issue?

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure it is breaking at that exact line? Because everything you have there looks fine, as long as your client is set up correctly and you have a valid ARN.

[This may be helpful](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/sns_example_sns_Publish_section.html), it has a .NET sample for this action in the AWS Code library. If you clone the repository, [the example](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/dotnetv3/SNS#code-examples) has a console app you can run, and you could use your own Topic for testing. It might help you isolate the issue.